# How to access the object hierarchy shown by a GWT CellTree from a custom SelectionEventManager?

Tags: java, gwt

I'd like to make a custom `CellTree` that would use checkbox based cells (I would like to use tristate checkboxes so will have to write a custom cell). I would like to make the parent node selection to select all its children and also if all children is selected then the parent node's checkbox should become selected too. If not all children are selected only some of them, then the parent checkbox should be in the so called "third state".

To achieve this I made a custom `public class TriStateSelectionEventManager extends DefaultSelectionEventManager<TopologyNodeRep>` and wanted to override its

```
public void doMultiSelection(MultiSelectionModel<? super TopologyNodeRep> selectionModel,
                                 HasData<TopologyNodeRep> display,
                                 int row,
                                 TopologyNodeRep rowValue,
                                 DefaultSelectionEventManager.SelectAction action,
                                 boolean selectRange,
                                 boolean clearOthers)
```

method. I thought this is the most appropriate way to implement this requirement. My problem is that from this method I cannot access the tree data. The received `display` object contains all the necessary information, but it cannot be accessed as it is a `CellTreeNodeView.NodeCellList` instance that is a private inner class of a package access class.. :-(

Do you have any idea how to implement this requirement in GWT?

Comment: How about passing the underlying data as a constructor variable to your ``TriStateSelectionEventManager`` and then accessing it in the ``doMultiSelection`` function or alternatively you could pass the ``Eventbus`` and then fire a event and handle the selection of all child elements outside.

Comment: If I had access to the data, manipulating the data is not the solution as I need to manipulate the selection, not the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `TopologyNodeRep` class have references to its childs and parents respectively?
In case it does you could retrieve the childs of a specific selected `TopologyNodeRep` instance and also select its childs automatically. 
Something like this:

```
List<TopologyNodeRep> childs = rowValue.getChilds();
for (TopologyNodeRep child: childs) {
    selectionModel.setSelected(child,true);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't have direct references. But thanks for the idea, worth considering :-)